# Dates got buggy when they are stored to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have two datepickers in format dd/mm/YYYY. Problem is that when I store them to database, they got buggy. Output is "1970-01-01'. I am also using mySQL STR_TO_DATE function and php built in function for date format...  I don't know why my dates are not working. Can someone told me why my dates got buggy?

Here is code that I am using:

```
$datumDO=$_POST['datepicker'];
$datumOD=$_POST['datepicker1'];
$time = strtotime($datumDO);
$NewDatum = date('d/m/Y',$time);    
$time = strtotime($datumOD);
$NewDatumOD = date('d/m/Y',$time);
    if ($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `cat-item` (id_cat, id_item, datumOD, datumDO) VALUES (?,?,STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d/%m/%Y'))")){
        $stmt->bind_param('iiss', $category, $item, $NewDatum , $NewDatumOD;
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: instead of using STR_TO_DATE, could you please try entering the dates as strings in the format YYYYMMDD ?

Comment: @amenadiel I tried that and they are still buggy.

Comment: Are your sure your datumOD and datumDO columns are date in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$datumDO= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
$datumOD= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker1']));
    if ($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `cat-item` (id_cat, id_item, datumOD, datumDO) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")){
        $stmt->bind_param('iiss', $category, $item, $datumDO, $datumOD;
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

try this.....hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If your datepickers are providing dates in `dd/mm/YYYY` format (with `/` as the separator), the inputs to your functions are incorrect.

**strtotime**:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the **American m/d/y** is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601
>   (YYYY-MM-DD) dates [ [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) ]